# how to read a pdf file using lisp

Tags: lisp

how we can read a pdf using lisp and separate the table of content. This can be done by other languages but in lisp this is bit difficult any can help me with a sample code?

http://www.rajive-hsenid.appspot.com/

this is done by python now i am trying to do this with lisp

please help me..

Answer (score 6):

Try cl-pdf-parser--I found it on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=cl-pdf-parser). This code is too big to post here. Look for the file *pdf-parser.lisp*(insider the archive).

cl-pdf-parser comes with examples: http://www.fractalconcept.com/download/cl-pdf-current.tgz

Answer (score 1):

Followup to this since the original link listed by @frayser doesn't work (but is available in the Wayback Machine; for the curious: https://web.archive.org/web/20200618163802/http://www.fractalconcept.com/asp/w0Rj/sdataQ0v$QsmkCsLvDM==/asdataQuQhZ0XhCuWs).

The code is now on GitHub: https://github.com/archimag/cl-pdf which I have started off with the following that works for me (Debian 11.6, SBCL 2.1.1.debian):

```
# Using quicklisp; there are tutorials for quicklisp out there, and if
# you use another package manager then adapt the following to that.
cd ~/.quicklisp/local-projects/
git clone --recursive https://github.com/archimag/cl-pdf.git
```

Then fire up your Lisp REPL and:

```
(ql:quickload "cl-pdf-parser")
(in-package pdf)
(read-pdf-file "/path/to/my-file.pdf")
```

And so far it's parsed the PDF I'm interested in right now; might followup some more later, but hopefully that's enough to get people started, as the source is available.